# How to identify when a multibranch job has been triggered by a cron schedule?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I can have my master branch jobs run hourly like this:

```
String cron_string = BRANCH_NAME == "master" ? "@hourly" : ""

pipeline {
  agent none
  triggers { cron(cron_string) }
  stages {
    // do something
  }
}
```

But I want some specific behavior for that hourly run- like only running certain stages for the hourly cron triggered run.

Is there any way to identify if a multibranch job was triggered by a cron schedule from inside the pipeline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`currentBuild.getBuildCauses()` should work.

https://opensource.triology.de/jenkins/pipeline-syntax/globals#currentBuild

Comment: does that work? what is the "cause" for a cron job? is it `currentBuild.getBuildCauses('hudson.triggers.TimerTrigger$TimerTriggerCause')` ?

Comment: This or Trigger.Cron (https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/triggers/package-summary.html). I haven't used either, so you need to try both (or just println the entire list of causes)

Comment: If the a crone trigger than  `currentBuild.getBuildCauses` will give `TimerTrigger`